# DC DC converter control design, PID vs compensators

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control

I have to make a dc dc converter to power a resistive load, and I have reviewed various applications notes,  and applications reports like SLVA633 and SLVA662

They make uses of an compensator design approach, a type II or type III compensator whether is a current control or a voltage control,  then I have the doubt about the use of the pid control instead of the compensator approach, in the reports states that type II compensators is the industry standard for current mode control and I haven't found the same amount of information if any  about an analog pid design/analysis for dc dc conventers

Answer (score 1):

A type III compensator and PID controller are essentially similar.  A voltage mode compensator in a SMPS usually puts a pole at the origin (integrator), and a pair of zeros somewhere around the LC resonant frequency (differentiator=zero) and provides a way to adjust the gain (proportional term). (The final poles go maybe at the ESR zero and half the switching frequency to reduce noise.) A PID controller provides a pair of zeros and a pole at the origin, so if your PID implementation modifies the open loop gain so that it's stable with good gain and phase margin you have accomplished the same thing.

Some SMPS controllers have a tranconductance compensation amp so you are limited to putting compensation components from the output to ground, but if you're putting together your own control loop there's no reason you can't use your own implementation of PID control.

Comment: But there is a clear advantage at  choose one or another? I would like to make it digital, I suppose that I can design the compensator as a digital filter, also if you have about any application note on implementing a pid either analog or digital it would be great.

Comment: No, there's no clear advantage, the results are essentially identical.  If you're doing it in digital just design the filter with the poles and zeros where you need them to stabilize the loop, whether you call it a PID or "compensator" really doesn't matter.  For current mode you don't necessarily need the additional zero that the PID provides but you can still stabilize the loop.